# How to predict where segmentation fault occurs

Tags: segmentation-fault, signals, infinite-loop

How to predict where segmentation fault occurs if we are increasing a pointer in a infinite loop?

I have thought that we can use the alarm signal handler and it will be invoked after every 1 second and it will print the address pointed to by the pointer so that when the segmentation fault would occur we would get a very nearby address where it occurred.

Could there be more better solution? If there then please tell. Thanks in advance

Code :

```
#define SECOND 1

int *str;

void  ALARMhandler(int sig)
{
     signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN);      


printf("ptr=%u \n",*str);

     alarm(SECOND);                     /* set alarm for next run   */
     signal(SIGALRM, ALARMhandler);     /* reinstall the handler    */
}



int main()
{

int *ptr;
str=&ptr;
int a;
ptr=&a;
signal(SIGALRM,ALARMhandler);    
alarm(SECOND);                   


for(;;)
{
    ptr++;


}

return 0;

}
```

Comment: In the general case, it is an intractable or unsolvable issue (related to the halting problem).

Comment: What i have thought, its not working, segmentation fault is not occurring(i have checked for about 2 minutes) and the infinite loop is incrementing the pointer continuously.

Comment: Show your actual code, enable warnings and debug info at compilation time (e.g. `gcc -Wall -g`) and use a debugger (e.g. `gdb`)

Comment: Why do you ask? What is your motivation? What do you want to achieve??

Answer (score 2):

First, with a big enough optimization level, the compiler might remove your infinite `for(;;)` loop entirely.

Showing your pointer only every second is not very meaningful. A typical processor execute billions (ie 10<sup>9</sup>) of machine instructions per seconds. On a 32 bits machine, this means that the entire process address space could be scanned in very few seconds.

Then, on Linux/AMD64 (and Linux/x86), the stack grows downwards (from higher addresses to lower addresses); since you start with a local variable near the `main` call frame, you will very quickly get outside (i.e. before = higher the beginning of your stack).

You could perhaps catch the `SIGSEGV` signal; this means installing a processor- and system- specific handler with [sigaction(2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/sigaction) system call, using the `SA_SIGINFO` flag.

Actually, on Linux, you might want to retrieve your process address map, by reading `/proc/self/maps` (or perhaps `/proc/self/smaps` or some other file inside the [proc(5)](http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc) pseudo-file system); this should give you the segment to which a given address belongs to, and then you would be able to understand where that segment ends.